# What is meant by this weird docker command?

Tags: linux, macos, docker, compilation, owncloud

Following the [docs on compiling the OwnCloud sync client](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.1/building.html#windows-installer-build-cross-compile) I'm trying to build the client for Windows. I managed to build the docker image and according to the docs I now need to run the following command to start compiling:

```
docker run owncloud-client-win32:2.1 -v "$PWD:/home/jenkins/client" admin/win32/docker/build.sh $(id -u)
```

But I get the this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '-v' not found or does not exist..
```

Looking through the [docs on docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) I don't see any mentioning of the -v command, so that makes sense. I wonder what the devs actually meant by this though.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here and how I could possibly proceed? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the right syntax (I guess):

```
docker run -v "$PWD:/home/jenkins/client" owncloud-client-win32:2.1 admin/win32/docker/build.sh $(id -u)
```

the `-v` argument is for setting a volume, or in other words, a folder that will survive to container deletion (except if you ran `docker rm -v container` to remove it).

More on docker volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

Comment: That gets me a bit further, but I now get `docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'admin/win/docker/build.sh' not found or does not exist..`. Any idea about this one?

Comment: as it says, the build.sh script is not there... try to find the correct path to that script...

Comment: maybe `/home/jenkins/client/admin/win32/docker/build.sh` ?

Comment: Well, the path is actually correct. I also tried an absolute path at which I can `cat` the `build.sh` file, so I'm 100% sure the path is correct. Doesn't the error say that the container doesn't expect this argument? I'm unsure of what arguments normally look like. Are arguments often bash scripts?

Comment: then maybe it is not executable

Comment: arguments are whatever correct linux command, and yes, bash scripts are more than often arguments

Comment: @kramer65 any news ?

Comment: Excuse me for taking so long, but I'm kinda stuck. The path is 100% correct and I chmodded the file to 777, but I still get the same error. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109816/discussion-between-n00dl3-and-kramer65).